# Get the return value of a springboot api in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im doing this request to an api in react:

```
return fetch(url, {

        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            player: param

        })
    })
```

And this is what my java method returns :

```
return "an example string";
```

When trying to access that same content in react, I did this:

```
service.setXMLFile("PlayerList", playerAux).then((response=>{
        window.alert(JSON.stringify(response))
    }))
```

What I want to do is to print that same string on my react frontend but I cant access it. When I print my response the value is {}
Thanks.

EDIT:

Call to my service on react:

```
createXml = () => {

    let playerAux = [];

    this.state.playerList.player.forEach((player) => {

        let jsonPlayer = {
            idPlayer: player.idPlayer,
            playerName: player.playerName,
            broadcastChannel: player.broadcastChannel,
            clusterName: player.broadcastChannel,
            playerAlias: player.playerAlias
        }

        playerAux.push(jsonPlayer);

    })

    let service = new FileConfigurationService();

    service.setXMLFile("PlayerList", playerAux).then((response=>{
        window.alert(response)
    }))
}
```

API call:

```
setXMLFile = (xmlFile, param) => {

    let url = this.baseUrl + "/setXmlFile/" + xmlFile;
    window.alert("BOAS POST " + url)
    url = encodeURI(url);

    return fetch(url, {

        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            player: param

        })
    })

}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide further details about the setXMLFile() method?

Comment: The method just has the URL to comunicate to the Java application,the param variable on the parameters and that fetch

Comment: Only this one end point isn’t working? Or is it a complete new applications?

Comment: The endpoint works and the java code works as well,everything works but I cant access the response content of my response variable

Comment: post the function for fetching data

Comment: Again,everything works,I have updated my question with what the postman receives as a return value when the input is wrong

Comment: but your java service doesn't work, from the screenshot it is throwing an exceeption.

Comment: The java service creates a file with the specifications that the user inserts on the frontend,that file is created if the input is right and if not returns the message you can see on my postman image.It works,I can assure you that, I just cant access the response on react

Comment: Its throwing a string with why the file could not be created,in this case a field was missing

Answer (score 0):

fetch returns a promise, you need to handle that promise using await or then.

like

```
fetch().then().catch()
```

or

```
await fetch()
```

change your function to handle the promise

```
setXMLFile = async (xmlFile, param) => {

let url = this.baseUrl + "/setXmlFile/" + xmlFile;
window.alert("BOAS POST " + url)
url = encodeURI(url);

const response = await fetch(url, {

    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        player: param

    })
 });

return await response.json();

}
```